# Can't support multiple screen sizes Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I need some help with design for multiple screen sizes in Android.

I created layout, layout-sw600dp, values, and values-sw600dp with dimens.xml file with dimension for layout-sw600dp.

But when I run application in emulator with 7" tablet, the design is not set up properly.

How I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: have u tried layout-hdpi or layout-xhdpi? depends on your device screen.

Comment: This seems to work. Anyway I have also  Google AdMob in my project, but it's not set up properly also on larger screens. How I could fix that?

Answer (score 0):

> The fundamental size of a screen, as indicated by the shortest dimension of the available screen area. Specifically, the device's smallestWidth is the shortest of the screen's available height and width (you may also think of it as the "smallest possible width" for the screen). You can use this qualifier to ensure that, regardless of the screen's current orientation, your application has at least  dps of width available for its UI. **the device's smallestWidth does not change when the screen's orientation changes.**

Try to use `layout-w600dp` instead of `sw`.