# Complete List of Folder names in android resource

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I wan to know the list of folders in android . By going through

[Article 1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

[Article 2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) in [developer site](http://developer.android.com/index.html)  and

[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761406/complete-list-of-all-android-resource-folders) from stackoverflow I got an idea about it . but still it doesn't satisfy need

I mean there are many folders for kepping  layouts, drawable and values on the bases of Screen size of devices and the language we are using

For eg: arabic `layout-ar` .

Even on the base of Layout  direction  `layout-ldrt`

I want to know detail about it.  It says that some folders are deprecated ( [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308284/1450401) ) in higher version of android api . Even there is folder like `layout-w600dp` ( [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16894094/1450401) ) I'm sorry that was a new to me

so somebody please elaborate about this topic and provide the data about list of folders using in `res`

Comment: The first two links you gave in the question already provides the list of combination for the folders inside `res` and their meanings... What exactly do you mean by "detail about it"?

Comment: @TactMayers i heard that some folders were depricted from Android 3.2 .i was asking about that

Comment: You should edit your question to emphasize what you wanted to ask then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have android sdk installed? If you're running windows you may want to have a look at

```
your_sdk_path\sdk\platforms\android-17\data\res
```